# "Group by" advanced SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I am learning SQL queries. I attach the picture of my models above. 
Given a group of "peopleIDs", how could I find how many types are available and under each type how many "Magics" are there. 
The multiplicity between "people" and "result" is one-to-many, "result" and "Magic_score" one-to-many, and "magic_score" and "magic" many-to-one.
Do I first get "all available types" and then count "magic" under each type?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you mean how many `Result.Type` or how many `Magic.Type`?

Comment: @NetMage Thanks for your reply. Result.type and magic.type are the same things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean `Result.Type`, you can join the tables and group by the `Type` and count the `Magic`s.

```
SELECT r.Type, COUNT(m.Magic_ID), COUNT(r.peopleID)
FROM Result r
INNER JOIN Magic_Score ms ON r.Result_ID = ms.Result_ID
WHERE r.peopleID in groupPeopleIDs
GROUP BY r.Type
```

Given that the `Result.Type` and `Magic.Type` are the same, and that every `Result` only points to `Magic`s with the matching type, the answer should be the same, but grouping by `Magic.Type` would be similar:

```
SELECT m.Type, COUNT(m.Magic_ID)
FROM Result r
INNER JOIN Magic_Score ms ON r.Result_ID = ms.Result_ID
INNER JOIN Magic m ON ms.Magic_ID = m.Magic_ID
WHERE r.peopleID in groupPeopleIDs
GROUP BY m.Type
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, Result.type is the same as Magic.type.

Comment: @user3369592 that's not a fantastic design then, why not use `Magic_ID`? Unless either the Result or Magic table is enormous this type of denormalization does not make sense.

Comment: @pim I agree with you but I am not allowed to change the design..

Comment: I added the other grouping.

Comment: @NetMage. Thanks!! If I also want to know how many people under each type, all I need to do is add "COUNT(people.peopleID)"  ?

Comment: @NetMage. Do we actually need to join "magic_score" with "Magic"?

Comment: You do if you want to group by `Magic.Type` but not in the first query - I simplified it. Nice catch.